# Vue cli on android

Tags: android, terminal

I use a mouthstick to opeate by android tablet(since i am paralysed and cant use a laptop)..
I know front end development and wanted to learn Vuejs2.
So i need to use the CLI  that Vue js offers i.e vue-cli
So for the command line interface i downloaded the termux app from play store which is a terminal for Android and file with many Linux packages
Using this i installed nodejs and vue-cli
But for the next step to proceed i ha Ave to execute the command

```
npm install
```

And then

```
npm run dev
```

The vue-cli is getting installed without any errors but running the `npm run dev` is giving many errors in the terminal and the app is not being started

What shall i do?
Tried same with learning angular 2 but same issue

Any help and suggestions are appreciated

Comment: the error i got was permission denied error.....i think you need to root the device and then it may work.....but I don't want to root my phone :(

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem.  It turned out that I had created my project in a directory out side the "storage" directory created by Termux.  I don't know the details as to why, but apparently that was the problem.  I re-created the vue project in a directory underneath the "storage" directory and those problems resolved.  I still haven't gotten the project to run, though.  Now I'm getting a single error about an unhandled promise rejection.  Still researching that one...